# Could any of these university courses be a good MSc for a quantum computing future job/research?

Tags: research

I'm a Politecnico di Torino student currently enrolled - and close to graduate - in Electronics and Communications engineering. As such, I know the basics of analog electronics, digital electronics, signal processing and of course anything that has to do with communications, especially TCP/IP on all levels, even physical. I like the theory of information and signal modulation, and I also like higher levels in TCP/IP, knowing some basic algorithms and protocols; I'm not new to this. Furthermore, I hate analyzing analog circuits, but I love digital electronics and LTI systems theory (including discrete analysis like Z-transform of signals, FFT, etc). Along with this, I have a strong personal background on operating systems and programming (mainly C/C++; but I also have a big experience in higher-level languages). My initial thought was to engage with **embedded systems** as my MSc, in order to strengthen my knowledge in OSes (since I'm not used to real-time ones) and find a mix between my hobby, programming, and something that has to do with telecommunications, signal analysis, or anyways low-level computer stuff (for example, I love memory management and CPU arch, and I'd love to learn more about them). So, why not, this sounds like a good mix.

However, I've recently discovered that one of our free-choice exams includes, weirdly, an introduction to Quantum Information, Quantum Computing, and Teleportation at the Bachelor's level. I was selected for this and I will start the lectures next semester. I still have no idea how the whole thing works, but the concept of quantum computing seems extremely interesting to me, right now. In case I end up loving this course, I think I'd be wanting to do something about quantum computing in my future Ph.D. program if I ever get to get into one.
At this point, I got some choices:

- *MSc in Computer/Electronic Engineering with Embedded Systems path* - I think this would be good especially for getting to know into details how these systems work on a low level, how classical architectures work before heading to a hypothetical quantum computing background
- *MSc in Physics of Complex Systems* - this one is very interesting because it provides a lot of statistical inference, statistical quantum mechanics, and some quantum information theory backgrounds
- *MSc in Computer Engineering, Cyber Security path* - this one could be interesting if I want to operate with the security of quantum systems - I saw that, in telecommunications, there is something called a "quantum key sharing"; I'm not sure what it is, but sounds cool.
- *MSc in Computer Engineering, Software Engineering path* - interesting, but I'm not sure how good this could be.
- *MSc in Data Science and Engineering* - could be pretty cool, but I'm not sure how this could help with QC.

Do these courses make sense? In case they do, which one could be the best? I'm very interested in computer architecture and in telecommunications, and also in reverse engineering memory management, and data structures. One thing I absolutely love is working with bits, especially when it's about manipulating memory or also bitmasks, and I also am amazed and very interested in probability when it's applied to signals (power spectral densities and that stuff), and in general statistical inference. I hate purely analog circuits analysis because, to me, they have lots of inconsistencies and I'm not good at re-modeling circuits from different points of view, let alone all the awful approximations that are often taken for granted in these courses. I also love physics, especially electromagnetism, and stochastic processes-based physical theories, so Physics of Complex Systems could be interesting.

What do you think? Do any of these make sense?
I could also switch university, but quantum computing courses at MSc level are extremely rare and they're usually found in mostly Physics and Technology courses, and furthermore, it would be a great problem with funding, but I suppose I could make some more sacrifices.

I am really sorry for my long post and I hope this is the right subsite, and I hope this wasn't already asked (couldn't really think anything about it, especially with these courses). For any suggestions, thank you in advance! I would really appreciate any tips. Have a good day!

Comment: Hi, Maurizio. I see that you've put in quite some effort in writing up this question but unfortunately, such [career-advice](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319) type questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Oh, I see; I was thinking indeed that this could be a wrong "subsite", but I wasn't sure of what to put it on... Is it possible to mitigate or does the post have to get deleted and then a new one should be created?

Comment: Anyways thanks :) I see that MS.c.'s are quite limited, or at least in my country; I was planning on improving my skills with classical architectures and then pursuing through a Ph.D. that actually focused in QC. Still, I'm actually so confused because all of these topics sound sooo interesting and so I would love to find something like an intersection. I guess any choice could be the right one though :) thank you again!

Comment: To be honest, this question isn't a good fit for the Stack Exchange format and would not be on-topic anywhere on the network. However, even if it gets closed, the comment section will still remain open and people might be able to give you some advice. You could try other forums like Reddit where such questions tend to be more acceptable. Good luck with your endeavors!

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I'll try as many sources as possible :)

Comment: as noted above, this kinds of questions are off-topic here. You might have better luck asking people in the chat rooms about these kinds of topics, either [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74398/the-classical-channel) or on the [physics one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74398/the-classical-channel). Also, regarding the question, it could also be a good idea to ask someone working on quantum information in your university about this, provided there are people doing quantum info there. The professor teaching the introductory class you mentioned being the obvious first choice

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! I'll try asking my professor and then once I have my view a bit more clear I'll come back to the chat. Thanks for your suggestions!